# PHP añadir un array simple dentro de un array

Tags: php, array

Array push no funciona como creo que debería funcionar,
necesito que agregue un array sin que agregue un 0

```php
$arr = array(
   "name" => "n1"
);
array_push($arr, "agent" => "ag1");
```

Output que necesito:

```json
{
  "name": "n1",
  "agent":"ag1"
}
```

Intenté con esto, pero no es lo que necesito, ya que agrega un 0 de más.

```php
array_push($arr, array("agent" => "ag1"));
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "n1",
  "0": {"agent":"ag1"}
}
```

También intenté con esto, pero tampoco es lo que necesito, ya que muestra un cero como dato y no el "agent".

```php
array_push($arr, array("agent" => "ag1")["agent"]);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "n1",
  "0": "ag1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada la salida que buscas considero que:

- Sería mas simple el uso del método [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

  - De esta forma obtenemos un solo array resultante
  - Los valores de uno se anexan al final del primero

Entonces puedes tener tu array inicial y solo pasar como segundo argumento la clave y valor del nuevo array deseado así:

```
$data = array_merge($arr, ["agent" => "ag1"]);
```

Si ahora imprimimos dicha variable veremos una salida como esta:

```
Array
(
    [name] => n1
    [agent] => ag1
)
```

Desde este punto, ya solo necesitas el uso del método `json_encode` para transformar dicho array en la string json deseada.

**Ejemplo completo**

```
<?php

$arr = array(
   "name" => "n1"
);

$data = array_merge($arr, ["agent" => "ag1"]);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Salida:

> {"name":"n1","agent":"ag1"}

**Comentario final**

- Si deseas seguir usando `array_push` entonces te recomiendo mires los ejemplos propuestos en la zona de: [**User contributed notes**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)